# Iterate over the rows to find the breaks in the data

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I have the following table of data

```
Sam. Type  Trace
E18  A     0.124    
E28  A     0.114     
E25  A     0.128    
E99  B     0.132     
E18  B     0.111     
E25  B     0.108
E99  C     0.132     
E18  C     0.111     
...
```

What I need to do, is to identify when the "A" type of the data breaks, so I just need to compare each of the following **row** of the column **type** with the next one and create a new column which states the result of comparison.

This is what I want to get:

```
Sam. Type  Trace Categ.
E18  A     0.124   A 
E28  A     0.114     
E25  A     0.128    
E99  B     0.132   B  
E18  B     0.111     
E25  B     0.108
E99  C     0.132   C  
E18  C     0.111     
...
```

I have tried to start with smth like this to construct the base of the iteration but I can't make the proper comparison:

`for index, row in sorted_data.iterrows():
    if sorted_data['Type']== sorted_data['Type'].shift(-1):
        print('ok')`

Is there any other method to compare the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need test first duplicated values per `Type` column with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) or [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html), last set value by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

Difference in changed data - another group `A`:

```
m1 = sorted_data['Type'] != sorted_data['Type'].shift()
m2 = ~sorted_data['Type'].duplicated()

sorted_data['Categ.1'] = np.where(m1, sorted_data['Type'], '')
sorted_data['Categ.2'] = np.where(m2, sorted_data['Type'], '')
print (sorted_data)
   Sam. Type  Trace Categ.1 Categ.2
0   E18    A  0.124       A       A
1   E28    A  0.114                
2   E25    A  0.128                
3   E99    B  0.132       B       B
4   E18    B  0.111                
5   E25    B  0.108                
6   E99    C  0.132       C       C
7   E18    C  0.111                
8   E18    A  0.148       A        
9   E28    A  0.144                
10  E25    A  0.858
```